# how to integrate firebase analytics in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

i have use **FireBase analytics** process that is given in google but after that not track any data in **firebase analytics**.
how to integrate **firebase analytics** in android ?

Answer (score 3):

If you followed the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) then you'll have to wait for 24 hours to see the data in the console. It updates periodically.

Comment: I have a doubt please help to clear it... I have main launcher activity that is Login View and after Login I have Fragment Controller activity that control all the user's view screens or fragments. So My doubt is Do I need to put firebase analytic code that is this one:- 

private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

in both activities?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to implement Google Firebase Analytics to your Android App:

1. Add Google Firebase to your project. Register Your App at [Google Firebase Console][1]
2. If you're creating a new Firebase project, enable Google Analytics during the project creation workflow.
3. If you have an existing Firebase project that doesn't have Google Analytics enabled, you can enable Google Analytics from the Integrations tab of your Project settings.
4. Add the dependency for the Google Analytics Android library to your module (app-level) build.gradle file.

> **Java :** implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
>
> **Kotlin :** implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0'

5. Declare the com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics object at the top of your each activity:

> **Java :** private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
>
> **Kotlin :** private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics

6. Initialize it in the onCreate() method:

   **Java :**

   // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance...
   mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

   **Kotlin :**

   // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance..
   firebaseAnalytics= Firebase.analytics

You have successfully Integrated the Firebase Analytics in your App.

Now for **Logging Events** Follow the below procedure :

The following code logs a SELECT_CONTENT event when a user clicks on a specific element in your app.

**Java :**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

**Kotlin :**

```
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_ITEM) {
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image")
}
```

Comment: Don't know why but for Kotlin it gives me an error "Unresolved reference: param".

Comment: I have a doubt please help to clear it... I have main launcher activity that is Login View and after Login I have Fragment Controller activity that control all the user's view screens or fragments. So My doubt is Do I need to put firebase analytic code that is this one:- 

private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

in both activities?

Comment: @RohanHazarika Yes you need to put the Firebase Analytics code in each of your activities.